# setBasePackage() is undefined in Application.ApplicationConfig

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

`setBasePackage()` is undefined in `Application.ApplicationConfig`. Everything else is fine in my spring-data-neo4j project. How to resolve it?

I have extended Neo4jConfiguration yet not identified

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/

I copied the code from here -- exactly the same.

Comment: please post you code

Comment: added the link in edit. I actually am trying the example in that link from spring.io, so the code is exactly the same and I am using STS suite to run the code